# Why the server responded with a status of 400

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am trying to create a sharepoint list using REST call. But i am getting error message: 'The server responded with a status of 400.'

Below is my code. Not able to understand where I am doing mistake:

url: https://abcTest.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists.
digest: I am getting from a different function call.

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method:  'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
       'X-RequestDigest': digest
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       __metadata: {
         type: 'SP.List`
    },
       AllowContentTyes: true,
       BaseTemplate: 100,
       ContentTypesEnabled: true,
       Description: 'List description',
       Title: 'MyList'
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'

===>   'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'

And :  method:  'POST'`  ===>     method:  'POST'

Make sure parameter is json data.

Comment: Sorry, that was the typo. I have edited my question

Comment: Finally I could able to figure out the issue.  Had to remove the __metadata